# PowerShell script to parse files from root folder

Tags: powershell, parsing

I am working on following script which tries to read a text file, and then run an algorithm with the collected data. The algorithm must be applied to each file in the current folder, so there are 2 main loops.

Loop 1 is for files in folder.

Loop 2 is for the text line entries used in the algorithm.

Loop 3 is for the algorithm itself.

```
#$path = (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName
$path = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$files = Get-ChildItem "$path\test" -r # root path $PSScriptRoot

#echo $path
#echo $files
#echo $files.Count
ForEach ($file in $files){

    echo "the value of i is" $i
    #echo $file.FullName
    #iterate through files from the current folder.
    $data = Get-Content -Path $files.FullName

    #echo "$data"

    # parse DisabledFeatures.txt file as array of strings (1 string per line of the file)
    $feature = Get-Content "$path\Disabled_Features.txt"
    #echo $feature.Count
    #iterate for each string entry in $feature array (read from txt file)
    for($counter=0; $counter -lt $feature.Count; $counter++){

        #retrieve array value to use it in the main algorythm
        $groupID = $feature[$counter]
        echo $groupID
        $data | ForEach-Object -Begin { $ignore = $false; $levels = 0 } -Process {
            #Start ignoring text after we've found the trigger
            if($_ -match "^#ifdef $groupID") { 
                $ignore = $true
                ECHO "TRUE ifdef feature"  
            } 

            #Track nested groups
            elseif($ignore) {
                if ($_ -match '^#ifdef') {  
                    $levels++ 
                    echo "levels++"
                }
                elseif ($_ -match '#endif') {
                    if($levels -ge 1) { $levels-- }
                    #If no nesting, we've hit the end of our targeted group. Stop ignoring
                    else { $ignore = $false }
                    echo "stop ignoring"
                }
            }
            #Write line
            else { $_ }
            echo "write line"
        }  
    }
}
```

Edit: Updated script.

Comment: `$i -lt` and `$counter -lt`

Comment: "It does not seem to work" ... *how?* What result do you expect? What result do you actually get?

Comment: updated the script. it is intended to delete paragraphs stariting with #ifdef feature and ending with the correspondant #endif. So #ifdef #endif paragraphs in between don't care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script loops multiple times (once for each disabled feature) through each file content (`$data`), but you just write the result of the filter operation to the output without modifying `$data`.

So the next feature loop runs across the same, unmodified `$data` content. If the last disabled feature does not happen to be in the file, the last result returns the file content unchanged.

You need to capture the output of the innermost loop into a new string array, then assign that to `$data` before you run the next feature loop. You can then write that last `$data` to your desired output.

Minor improvement for readability: Use a foreach loop for the features, too, like

```
foreach ($groupID in $feature)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example about how should I pipe the captured string to $Data? 

I guess a simple way to capture it is by appending last $_ in string array?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Replace `$data | ForEach-Object` with `$data = $data | ForEach-Object` to capture the filtered output. You have to get rid of the `echo` statements though or change them to `Write-Host`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed !